# Changing letters in string to letter and number of frequency-python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, numbers

I'm looking for the solution to my problem. I want to make a program where someone inputs string and I cover it into something like this:

```
'ZZZZYYYZZ' -> 'Z4Y3Z2'
```

I'm open for any suggestions.

The code I did:

```
def compress(s):
    e={}
    if s.isalpha():
        for i in s:
            if i in e:
                e[i] += 1
            else:
                e[i] = 1
    else:
        return None    

    return ''.join(['{0}{1}'.format(k,v)for k,v in e.items()])

s=input("Write string: ")
compress(s)
```

This produces the wrong output

```
Write string: ZZZZYYYZZ
Y3Z6
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is called _run length encoding_ and there are several solutions on SO already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping of unsorted data into chunks is a job for [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> 
>>> s = 'ZZZZYYYZZ'
>>> ''.join('{}{}'.format(c, len(list(g))) for c, g in groupby(s))
'Z4Y3Z2'
```

Detrails on what `groupby` produces here:

```
>>> [(c, list(g)) for c, g in groupby(s)]
[('Z', ['Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z']), ('Y', ['Y', 'Y', 'Y']), ('Z', ['Z', 'Z'])]
```

**~edit~**

Slight memory optimization without intermediary lists:

```
>>> ''.join('{}{}'.format(c, sum(1 for _ in g)) for c, g in groupby(s))
'Z4Y3Z2'
```

**~edit 2~**

> Instead of C1 can we have just C?

```
>>> s = 'XYXYXXX'
>>> to_join = []
>>> groups = groupby(s)
>>> 
>>> for char, group in groups:
...:    group_len = sum(1 for _ in  group)
...:    if group_len == 1:
...:        to_join.append(char)
...:    else:
...:        to_join.append('{}{}'.format(char, group_len))
...:        
>>> ''.join(to_join)
'XYXYX3'
```

Comment: Thank you for your quickly reply. It works and thank you so much for the help. I couldn't find it as I wasn't sure how to define my problem. Now I understand everything >u<

Comment: I will definitely do this ^^ I am new here and I am learning everything. I have one more question- if there any chance to change displaying of one letter? For example instead of C1 have just C?

Comment: @KimikoSourire yes, but with this extra check it's probably more readable to write a traditional `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much- I was trying to do the loop but it didn't work well :< Now I understand and you made my day.

Answer (score 2):

This lends itself to a neat use of `zip`, allowing you to iterate over each character and the next character:

```
s = 'ZZZZYYYZZ'
out = ''
count = 1
for a, b in zip(s[:-1], s[1:]):
    print(a, b)
    if a != b:
        out += a + str(count)
        count = 1
    else:
        count += 1

out += s[-1] + str(count)
```

which gives `out` as `'Z4Y3Z2'`.

Comment: Right, I didn't think in that way. I was trying to create loop that compares two elements of list of string but it didn't work well. Thank you for your reply